# When should i use GPU if im rendering on cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

Here is my setup:

OS: Windows 8.1 x64 
CPU: Intel Core i7-4702MQ @2.2 GHz
GPU: Nvidia GTX 750M

Almost 100% of my renders have been done on CPU because every time I try to render on GPU (knowing I'm using `auto tile size`) I always get a significantly slower render time. I've seen a lot of people recommending GPU for renders as it can take up a chunk of the time required to render. My question is: when is it recommended to use a GPU to render and when is it better to stick to CPU render?

Comment: Grab yourself a better card and you'll get significant faster render times.

Comment: Given that you are using a laptop, you don't have much of a choice to change the GPU. The graphics card that you are using does not have a lot of CUDA cures.

Comment: yeah @cegaton you are right, thats why im saving for a desktop setup, hopefully a month from now and ill get it, cuz render times are growing day after day, i just hit the 41 hours per render lol its frying my laptop.

Comment: @MarioAbouSamra I edited your question. In the future, please consider [double-checking that you capitalize "I" and the beginnings of sentences, use apostrophes, and follow other simple grammar rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/9074921). This will make your questions easier to read! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends which device has better compute performance. Usually that's GPU in desktops and CPU in non-gaming laptops.

Also you can be baking simulations on CPU and render at the same time using GPU.

Latest 2.79 [Blender builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/) offer rendering on both CPU and GPU at the same time.